# How can I bring the tableview in front of all views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, popup, dropdown

I have a viewcontroller which i am showing as a popup. The popup has two textfields with dropdown(the dropdown is a tableview which is subview of superview).So whenever I show the dropdown it is just taking the height of popup and the complete dropdown is not visible so the user is not able to select value from last rows.So I want to show the dropdown in front of all views so that the complete dropdown will be visible and the user will be able to select any value. I tried `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.tableView];`  and `self.tableView.layer.zPosition = 1;` both did not help me. How to do this?

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: dont use zPosition

Comment: yeah since it is not helping I removed it

Comment: If I understand correctly what you're describing, it seems that your tableview (dropdown) is contained within the popup (another VC) who's view clips to bounds. You might try to set `clipToBounds` to `YES`. Also, you might try looking at the exploded view of your UI and try to figure out the issue from there - this got me out of trouble many times.

Comment: @CatalinM I am not getting what you are trying to say

Comment: Default behaviour for views is to not display any content that extends outside its bounds. The problem you're describing is that your tableview extends outside the bounds of its superview and this is why you're not seeing it fully. It has nothing to do with the Z position. You need to set the `clipToBounds` property of the superview to `NO` and that should fix it (assuming your tableview has a correct frame). You might want to post a print screen so we can better understand the issue. PS: I had a typo in my first comment... it should've read `NO` for the property, not `YES`. Sorry

Comment: Yeah I tried that and no change.I have posted a picture

Comment: I don't think you've set the property on the right UIView. When setting `clipToBounds` to `NO`, your rounded corners should break if I remember correctly.

Comment: I tried `self.tableView.clipsToBounds = NO;` and it is not working

Comment: @CatalinM Is there anything else I am missing?

Comment: You need to understand how views work and what `clipsToBounds` does. Please refer to the documentation for this. Regarding your actual problem you need to set that property to `NO` on the superview of the tableview, not on the actual tableview. That will allow the system to display subviews that extend past the superview's bounds, which is the case with your tableview.

Comment: Even so, you might have an issue where the tableview extends under the keyboard and thus is still not completely usable. You might consider making the tableview as big as the popup and let users scroll. Even better, you can use an UIPickerView for this scenario (instead of that tableview), which is a more "iOS" way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

Add tableView to the window.

`let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!
 window.addSubview(tableView)`

Comment: You have to increase the height of popup at the time when the dropdown view gets open. You can calculate the height of pop up by multiplying the height of cell with total number of elements in tableview. Hope this help

Comment: I can not do that because the popup should be of fixed height

Comment: Than you have to put it into the scrollview.